# How do I add Product Name on Confirm Uninstall Prompt?

Tags: installshield, installscript-msi, installshield-2015

I have created an InstallScript MSI project installer and during its uninstallation, when I click on Uninstall option in Add\Remove windows a Confirm Uninstall prompt appears with Yes or No button.

What I want is to display the product name as a heading instead of Confirm Uninstall message at the top of the prompt and I am not able to find that option in InstallShiled 2020 R3 from where I could add the product name as heading in confirm uninstall prompt, could you please help me in letting know from where can I update the Confirm Uninstall message with the product name?

I am attaching both the screenshot for reference, the one which I want to be updated and the other one which is updated with product name but not sure how it was updated.

This is what I want in the another screenshot to be added i.e. Product Name.
[image]

Currently, it shows Confirm Uninstall message by default.
[image]

Comment: Some other people on this chat, way smarter than me, will probably know for sure but I believe this is part of the Windows installer service and can't be changed.

To be sure I would go to the Direct Editor in IS and search for "Confirm Uninstall" in the ISString table. If you find it trace the string back to the dialog to confirm it's what you want to change.

Comment: No, I couldn't find the  "Confirm Uninstall" in sting editor not in the direct editor.

Comment: If it's part of the Windows installer service then it won't have an entry there. That leads me to believe that it can't be set.

Comment: I think there would be some where in the InstallScript MSI project an option to update it. As it was updated in the above screenshot couple of years back by someone in the team..